# my .attrs function is not working in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner programmer and I was trying to create my hangman game and importing data with Beautiful Soup but when I copied the same exact thing as the youtuber his code worked and mine didn't. I have tested and the problem is the `.attrs` function.

I have tried looking if I had made a typo but I am pretty sure I didn't and I have also made sure I had downloaded all the packages needed and looked through the tutorial multiple times. The tutorial is by https://freecodecamp.org

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = 
requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films')

src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
results = []
for i in soup.find_all('th'):
    a_tag = i.find('a')
    results.append(a_tag.attrs['title'])

print(results)
```

Comment: how do I do it on a nonetype

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the error because not all the items in the list `soup.find_all('th')`  have tag `a`, and if you fix this, not all the items will have `title` , so try like this:

```
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
results = []
for i in soup.find_all('th'):
    if i.find('a'):
        a_tag = i.find('a')
        if a_tag.get('title'):
                results.append(a_tag.attrs['title'])
print(results)
```

Note:I tried not to reflector your code, and we can made it better :)